# How to create SSIS Boolean data type variable programmaticaly using C#?

Tags: ssis

How to create SSIS Boolean data type variable programmatically using C# ? I have gone through so many forums and  blogs but everywhere it was mentioned that the initial value will be taken for the datatype.

So i really don't understand how to create `boolean` datatype variable using C# ?

Comment: You title says `C` and your question says `C#`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah it's C# only !! Appology for the same

Comment: `bool demo = true;`

Comment: This is the variabke for C# and i am looking for the creation of ssis package variable using C# code

Answer (score 5):

Freehanding the code, it would be something like

```
Package p = new Package();
string variableName = "MyVariableName";
bool readOnly = false;
string namespace = "User";

var v = p.Variables.Add(variableName, readOnly, namespace, true);
```

The [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.variables.add.aspx) method of the Variables collection is what you're looking for. Based on the type of object you pass in for the fourth parameter, `true` in this case, will set the type within SSIS. Quirky way of doing it but that is how variable creation works.

If you want to put an expression on it, while this linked code is for the EzAPI, it's the same code [Variables and Expressions with SSIS EzAPI](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2012/01/variables-and-expressions-with-ssis.html)

```
v.EvaluateAsExpression = true;
v.Expression = "true";
```

Comment: Thanks man !! But i know this.. i am looking how to make this variable as boolean.

Comment: I don't understand, this makes an SSIS package with a variable of type Boolean

Comment: @AnkushVerma Could you help me understand what you're looking for? The above creates an SSIS package that will contain an SSIS Variable of type Boolean. Is this not what you were looking for?